# Dynamic Mod_Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm looking for help creating a mod_rewrite rule for my website.

Here is an example of what the current link looks like http://soccersurfer.com/profile.php?id=3 and I would like it turn into something like http://soccersurfer.com/players/cristiano-ronaldo/. I have a lot of links like this, so it's not as simple as doing it for one, but for "profile.php?id=X" where X is the profile number.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It can't be dynamic, but it can point to a PHP file that performs the lookup you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way would be:

```
RewriteRule ^/players/(.*?)/$ profile.php?name=$1
```

And in *profile.php*, add a possible argument (the name one) which lets you search the player in the database by his name rather than his ID.